# Can I Jumpstart with pos terminal broken

Tags: battery, jump-start

How can I jumpstart my car so I can get home to fix it. My only option is to jumpstart it . I’ve got jumper cables and AAA coming over

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly jump start it, but without the positive battery post hooked up it will cause you two possible issues.

1. Without it hooked up, you won't have the battery to provide the 12v buffering the rest of the electronic components need. This will most likely lead to failure of the electronics to include the alternator.
2. You'll run the risk of the loose positive terminal coming in contact with a ground. This will automatically cause the engine to shut down as well as all of the electronics. You could possibly mitigate this by wrapping it in something which would keep it from grounding out.

In either case (or both), there are serious downsides. Really, you need to find a way to re-attach the positive post. If you can't do this, you need to see about getting a tow truck to get you home or to a shop where it can be fixed.